# angular 2 - feed the table from multiple sources at once

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have to display a table of different roles with users assigned to them. I'm provided with #C API and I need to call three methods which will return data to feed the table. So I'm using `subscribe` in my table component.

```
this.roleService.getGlobalRoles().subscribe(res => this.tableContent = res);
```

Function `getGlobalRoles()` utilizes `forkJoin` to get all three responses at once.

```
getGlobalRoles(): Observable<RoleData[]> {
  return Observable.forkJoin(
    this.http.get(this.urlGlobalRoles).map(response => response.json()),
    this.http.get(this.urlUsers).map(response => response.json()),
    this.http.get(this.urlRolesEnum).map(response => response.json())
  ).map(res => this.processData({ globalRoles: res[0], users: res[1], rolesEnum: res[2] }));      
}
```

Method `processData` combines those three response into a single `RoleData` object and push it to the array of `RoleData` objects.

```
processData(combined): RoleData[] {
    var result = new Array<RoleData>();

    for (let rawData of combined.globalRoles) {
        let role= rawData as RoleData;
        role.fullName = this.getFullName(combined.users, rawData.userId);
        // Goes through the users response and returns the user full name 
        role.roleName = this.getRoleName(combined.rolesEnum, rawData.globalRoleKey);
        // Goes through the roles response and returns the role name
        result.push(role);
    }
    return result;
}
```

As you can see I'm using a method to update **RoleData** object with **fullName** and **roleName** in order to display them in the table. And then I have two separate methods `getGlobalRolesEnum` and `getUsers` which return **users** and **roles** respectively. I use them to feed the combo-boxes in editable popup.

Is there a way to simplify it? My solution works but I have a strong feeling that there is a better way.

**EDIT:** Just to make it clear what I'm trying to avoid is to have those two methods that do the same thing as a **getGlobalRoles()** only for separate calls.

```
getGlobalRolesEnum(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.getRolesEnumUrl)
        .map(response => response.json());
}

getUsers(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.getUsersUrl)
        .map(response => response.json());
}
```